# how to download and configure phpimage for TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html-editor

Actually I am looking for the best HTML editor for my CMS. With support for PHP and jQuery.

I found TinyMCE but it doesn't have image upload functionality. Then I found phpimage, but every time I go to http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2844769&group_id=103281&atid=738747 and click on "files", I get the normal TinyMCE.

My question is how to find phpimage to download and configure it.

If you know any other *free* HTML editor with image upload let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at: http://ckeditor.com/